# iBeacon Ranging in background

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-location, ibeacon

I'm trying to set my application as a way to just start ringing in the background and get a notification when the user hit the shoulder button or home button(not all the time) and I don't want using background mode. So I coded this in swift, it works when my app is working in foreground and background for 10 seconds and ranging won't be restarted when the user illuminates his phone's screen. First I started background task and then in app delegate I was trying to start ranging for the beacon in the immediate range. Can someone help me about this?

```
#Background Task   

    class BackgroundTask1 : NSObject {

        private let application: UIApplication!
        private var identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid


        init(application: UIApplication) {
            self.application = application
        }

        class func run(application: UIApplication, handler: (BackgroundTask1) -> ()) {

            let backgroundTask = BackgroundTask1(application: application)
            backgroundTask.begin()
            handler(backgroundTask)
        }

        func begin() {
            print("begin")
            self.identifier = application.beginBackgroundTask {
                self.end()
            }
        }

        func end() {
            if (identifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                application.endBackgroundTask(identifier)
            }
            identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        }}

#AppDelegate
    func init_()
        {
            let uuidString = "43F2ACD1-5522-4E0D-9E3F-4A828EA12C24"
            let beaconRegionIdentifier = "Hello"
            let beaconUUID:UUID = UUID(uuidString:uuidString)!
            beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: beaconRegionIdentifier)

            beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()


            if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
                locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
            locationManager!.delegate = self
            locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=false
        }

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            init_()

            locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)

            return true
        }

        func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
            // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        }

        var timer = Timer()
        func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
            BackgroundTask1.run(application:
            application) { (BackgroundTask1_) in

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            self.init_()
                            self.locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: self.beaconRegion)
                        }
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: Do you know if your `didRangeBeacons` method ever gets called?  If you don't know then you should add a debug line to determine if it gets called at all.

Comment: @davidgyoung thanks for your help, I changed my above code, it still cannot start ranging while the user illuminates his screen, I tested this app which you provided
"http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html" and it doesn't restart the clock when the phone exit or re-enter the region, I'm using iOS 10.3 and iPhone 6.